# Transfer image to a third party iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I would like to transfer an image from my app to a third party iOS app which I downloaded from app store. Please note that I have no access to the code of the third party app. However, I have following information about the third party app:

1. When I use UIDocumentInteractionController then I can see the app in the list, which points to the fact that this app has registered itself to be able to handle the image type data. I can select the app and the image opens up inside the app. Please also NOTE I can NOT use UIDocumentInteractionController as the solution because my app must ONLY be able to open the image in this specific third party app.

   ```
   if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"image", ofType: "png") {
           let documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
           documentController.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.firstButton.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)

       }
       else{
           print("no file found")
       }
   ```
2. I was also able to obtain the custom URL this app uses and I am able to open this app directly using following code:

   ```
   let url = URL(string: "customurl:exampleuser@example.com")
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
   ```

   where customurl is the url schem of this app.

Is there any way for me to use above two pieces of information about this third party app and **be able to open a image into this third party app directly on a button click from my app**?

Comment: Option 1 is much better because the user can choose what to do with the image and not be forced to use whatever app you are referring to.

Comment: That is exactly what I CAN NOT do. My app MUST be able to open the image ONLY in this specific third party app as a part of my use case.

Comment: Then you probably can't meet your requirements.

Comment: Sending to an explicit different app is something you would do with a custom URL scheme where the app accepted inbound data that way. If you do not own or control that app, and it offers no URL scheme that meets your needs, then you are stuck with document interaction and letting user choose. I see what you're asking but I don't believe there is any way of programmatically selecting a single destination to send data to.